# SolrNet - Customizing the Schema

Tags: solrnet

I am trying to implement SolrNet to be the search engine for our application.
I wanted to customize the SchemaXml before uploading XML Docs which will be the website sitemap.xml

The Sample SiteMapXML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"    
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><url>   
 <loc>http://www.google.com</loc>
 <lastmod>1900-01-01T00:00</lastmod>
 <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
 <priority>0.8</priority>
 </url>
 <urlset/>
```

Is it possible to change the schema to accomodate this xml schema or should I still be using the fieldname schema used 
something like given in the default Schema.

Can you provide me a sample how this can be done?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify the default sample schema to include the additional fields, check that then updated schema has been updated in the core then you are ready to import data to these additional fields.